# Mysqli multi-query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have searched and trying very much doing the multi query, but I still got no the thing what I want, probably because I am somewhat new with PHP and MySqli.
Here is my code, not done in multi query:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, LEFT(body, 100) AS body, category, name, posted from posts INNER JOIN
categories ON categories.category_id=posts.category_id order by post_id desc limit $start, $per_page");

$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $category, $name, $posted);
```

And I'd like to add basically this code to my query:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments where post_id='$id' ORDER BY comment_id DESC");
```

$db is connection to database. Thanks for advance!

I managed to fix my code, thanks for help!

Comment: Multi query? Could you elaborate, not a clue what you mean.

Comment: You're not preparing anything really. You should do it as such: `prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")`. Take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Well, doing multiple queries against the database. I am kind of bad at explaining things @Rogier

Comment: Do you mean you want to run both queries together? Like a join?

Comment: We'd need to see table structure because can't possibly guess which fields are in which table and you will have some ambiguity on field post_id at least

Comment: Well i understand all is difficult but try to use the naming correctly. As far as i know there is no such thing as "multi queries". Either there is a SQL UNION (select), you can have sql prepared (queries with parameters). Or you just send multiple queries ;-)  If you want to send multiple SQL statements, use a semi-colon between the queries (in one SQL query variable). But that only works for update, insert and deletes, if you want a resultset queries, you can only use union.

Answer (score -2):

using mysqli you can execute multiple queries, 
I am concatenating the query string for multiple queries and send them to my function i.e. **execute($q)** which contains mysqli_multi_query($this->con, $this->q) which is mysqli function and it runs great for me using PHP 5